# Error while I'm trying to decode using CodingKeys

Tags: swift, codable

**This my struct**

```
import Foundation
struct Settings: Hashable, Decodable{
    var Id = UUID()
    var userNotificationId : Int
}
```

**Coding Keys**

```
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        **case userNotificationId = "usuarioNotificacionMovilId"** (this is the line that gets me errors)

}
```

**init**

```
init(userNotificationId: Int){

        self.userNotificationId = userNotificationId
    }
```

**Decoder**

```
 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        userNotificationId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .userNotificationId) ?? 0
}
```

**Encoder**

```
init(from encoder: Encoder) throws{


  var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(userNotificationId, forKey: .userNotificationId)
}
```

I get the following error inside the coding method

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

Answer (score 0):

What is `init(from encoder: Encoder)` supposed to be? You're not conforming to `Encodable`, and if you were, you would need to implement `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws`, not another initializer.

That said, your explicit implementation of `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` does nothing different from what the compiler would synthesize for you, so it's better to remove it entirely as well.

```
struct Settings: Hashable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let userNotificationId: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case userNotificationId = "usuarioNotificacionMovilId"
    }

    init(userNotificationId: Int) {
        self.userNotificationId = userNotificationId
    }
}
```

is probably all you need.